# LGA 1155 Socket

Tags: cpu, motherboard, sockets

I have an ASUS CM6850 Motherboard and SIW reports:

```
Manufacturer    ASUSTeK Computer INC. Model
CM6850 Version  Rev 1.xx
Bridge North Bridge Intel Sandy Bridge Revision 09 
South Bridge    Intel H67 Revision B3 
CPU Name    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz 
Cpu Socket  Socket 1155 LGA 
BIOS Memory Type DDR3
```

Does this mean I can use my i7-2600 in ANY Mobo with a 1155 Socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can - since i7-2600 is designed for such a socket.

Manufacturer details in [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/52213#infosectionpackagespecifications).